# Disable p:rating after first click

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've a `<p:rating>`:

```
<p:rating id="ratingstars" value="#{image.rating}"   >
     <p:ajax event="rate" listener="#{imagesView.rating(image)}" />
</p:rating>
```

I would like to disable the component after the click/rate. I tried it with the BlockUI Component but it looks quite weird. There is an "disabled" attribute for the component but i don't know how to set it after the click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to disable the component based on a backend property:

```
<p:rating id="ratingstars" disabled="#{imagesView.ratingDisabled}" value="#{image.rating}"   >
    <p:ajax event="rate" listener="#{imagesView.rating(image)}" update="@this"/>
</p:rating>
```

and the `imagesView.isRatingDisabled()` has to return `false` after the `rating()` method has been called.